# Cant' access laravel public folder on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, ovh

I recently installed a Laravel app on an OVH shared hosting (pro so I have ssh access). This is my installation structure :

```
user
    app
       public
    www
```

Site access is under 'www' so I created a symbolic link there:
ln -s /home/user/app/public /home/user/www/index.html

The symlink is working and pointing to the laravel public folder when I check in Filezilla.
However when trying to access the site I am getting a 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try to give 755 permission to public folder

Comment: It's already 755...

Comment: So how are you writing the files to `user/app`? With `scp`,  `ftp` Or `git`? If git, are you using `sudo` anywhere (if at all possible in a shared host)? Are `app` and `www` owned by the same user/group? What user is running your web server process? Does this user have access to those files/directories?

Comment: I'm using git to upload to user/app, the owner is the ssh user I've been given. when I check the owner its is indeed the ssh user. Strangely when I do ls -l www I don"t see any owner at all..I don't think I can use sudo, I get "command not found" when I try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn’t get this to work, it is not a laravel related problem by the way, I assume ovh doesn’t allow symlinks to a protected folder on shared servers. A shame really but I ended up installing laravel in the www folder and preventing access to root with an .htaccess

Comment: Isn't it the type of link to the storage folder that isn't allowed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

your symbolic link is problem... you are pointing to `index.html` instead of **`index.php`**

try this:

```
ln -s /home/user/app/public /home/user/www/index.php
```

and Create and put this `.htaccess` file in your laravel installation(root) folder.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a multisite with `app/public` as root folder. Also, I wouldn't have a link to a file like `index.html`, but either to a folder like `../app/public`, e.g. to ensure `__DIR__` works correctly in php. (By the way, Laravel does not have an `index.html`).

I had a similar issue on an OVH shared server: `403 forbidden, You don’t have permission to access this resource` when accessing files in Laravel's public storage.

Tweaking `.htaccess` to `allow from all` or filesystem access control permissions to `777` `rwxrwxrwx` had no effect.

For me, the solution was to replace the absolute link `/home/accountname/www/***/storage/app/public` created by `php artisan storage:link` by the relative link `../storage/app/public`